# Why aren't the neat tools in Advanced Search more widely available across CiviCRM?

Tags: ui

If I look for, for example, participants for a given event, using Advanced Search, I can  - according the actions menu send them all an email using CiviMail/Mosaico without needing to first create a group for those contacts. But If I find those same contacts by searching for Participants, or using the drop-down participant options from the Manage Events screen, no such mailing option is offered.

If I use Advanced Search to look for, for example, participants for a given event, and I want to create a smart group form the results, there's a checkbox right there so that I can make that smart group a mailing list. But if I find those same people using a participant search, or once again using the drop-down participant listing options from the Manage Events screen, no such checkbox is provided.

What's that all about then?

Comment: Probably because whoever added those features didn't use participant search!

Comment: I think some of the differences (but not all) are if you search for participant records rather than contact records in the advanced search

Comment: i think the logic is about the 'entity'. you add a contact to a group. it is not a participant that is added to the group. hence if you want to add participants to a group do it via Adv Search. presumably to offer this via Find Participants requires more left joins which no-one contributed. i support your hope that these Actions could be more widely available but am pretty certain it won't happen without a funded effort